# what will happen if connection lost during transactional replication?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

what will happen if connection lost during transactional replication?

suppose db1 and db2 are replicating records but during replicating the connection between two databases lost.

what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing particularly bad.  When connectivity is restored, the distribution agent will contact the distribution database and ask for commands.  You need to be aware of the minimum retention period at the distributor though; if your loss of connectivity goes longer than that configured value, then you may have to reinitialize the subscriber as the commands necessary to continue replication might not be available at the distributor.  But if that happens, the situation is pretty obvious from the error message.